# Adding custom buttons and/or controls to Video.js

Tags: javascript, video.js

I looked at many the examples on adding custom controls to video.js.  I want to add a control bar that looks somewhat similar to this.

[image]

I have tried a few things with some fo the examples.  It does not have to look like this.  The most important part is the 4 buttons on the right.  I would prefer them images but I will use what I can.  If you believe video.js is not that best control for this I am open to any media player.

Comment: Can you add the code of what you already have?